# Django Models: Data Calculating

Tags: django

I have follow class

```
class Test(models.Model):
    t1=models.SmallIntegerField()
    t2=models.FloatField()
```

I want use the result of t1 * t2 in my Html. How can I do? 
I created a  function like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    t1=models.SmallIntegerField()
    t2=models.FloatField()
    def t3(self):
        return t1 * t2
```

But how to let's it work?

Comment: I highly suggest you take the [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial01/). It will guide you through the whole process of creating models, views and templates and will teach you, how these parts work together.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm new to Django so I have a lot of naive questions. I will accept your advice to see the tutorial. Thanks again. @Mischback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `self` prefix to `t1` and `t2` so that method knows what variables you want to multiply. Also, you can add `@property` decorator:

```
class Test(models.Model):
    t1=models.SmallIntegerField()
    t2=models.FloatField()
    @property
    def t3(self):
        return self.t1 * self.t2
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write it as,

```
class Test(models.Model):
    t1=models.SmallIntegerField()
    t2=models.FloatField()

    def __unicode__(self):
          return u"%s" % (self.t1* self.t2)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!You gave a correct approach to operational data. In addition, I have found the answer to this question. Thanks again.